# Implement explicit wait and fluent wait in QAF

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, qaf

I am new to perfetco-quantum framework.

I want to implement explicit wait and fluent wait in QAF framework. I tried with QAFwebelementexpectedcondition , qafwebdriverwait , qafwebelementwait. But I couldn't find any method so that I can call with an expected condition. Is there any way to implement this approach as in selenium ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different wait methods are available with element object, refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/wait_service.html)